# Memory stick pro vs memory stick pro duo

Tags: memorystick

I have an old camera (sony cybershotdsc-p72) which uses a memory stick pro.

And now I have to order a new memory stick, but I can only find a memory stick pro duo.

Are they compatible / wil it fit in my camera?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are compatible, but you need an adapter.

[Click here for a list of adapters](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=memory%20stick%20pro%20duo%20adapter&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=shop&cid=14776271143949234781&sa=X&ei=kcXvTd-cFef00gHf1sD3DA&ved=0CGUQ8wIwAA)

[Here is a 4 GB Pro Duo which includes the adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000GBO9IM)